# Как сделать, чтобы не расширялся layout из-за широкого background?

Tags: android, android-layout

Как сделать, чтобы не расширялся layout из-за широкого background. Например, у меня есть layout с размером 1, я ставлю background, и размер у меня становится 2. Как сделать, чтобы layout не удлинялся?

[image]

Comment: Использовать `9-patch drawables`?

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, задай `maxHeight()` элементу.